# rails 3 partial content_for not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I have a layout (application.html) that has this:

```
<!-- then anything added in the views -->
<%= yield :stylesheet %>
```

If I put this code in a 'root' template (ie the one called by an action directly) it renders on the page no problem:

```
<% content_for :stylesheet do %>
This is a test
<% end %>
```

But if I put the same thing in a partial it doesn't get rendered. The partial is rendered as such:

```
<%= render :partial => "detail" %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing rest of the related code it is hard to know for sure but it could be an ordering problem.

From a high level, when the page renders, it first loads the view (before the layout) and any partials in the view with content_for should work correctly.  However if this partial is being rendered in the layout instead of the view template, there is a chance the content_for will be called after the "yield :stylesheet" which would cause it to get ignored.

Comment: Hmm. no, the partial is in the view. But it is conditionally included... maybe it is doing that afterwards

Comment: I see.  Then it seems like it should work correctly.  I assume you have done a logger.debug inside the conditional logic to verify it is getting inside.  Other than that, it's unclear to me what is happening - we use conditional content_for blocks a lot for pixel dropping.

Comment: any way to see some more of the code or a reproduction on a nearly empty project?

Answer (score 0):

hmm, are you sure the partial is in the right directory.

I'm doing the exact same thing and it works no problem.  in my version of `home/_detail.html.erb` (i.e., it's in the home directory) in my `index.html.erb` page i just put the same code as you  have and it works no problem.  You sure the spelling is write on the file name, and that you saved the file?

Are you sure you're spelling content for correctly or don't have misplaced tags?  What do your tests say?

Also if it is in the head section, what if you added comment tags, instead of just plain text, maybe it doesn't like that?

Comment: thanks. the rest of the partial is rendering, just not the content_for blocks.